# Accent of the word "invalidity"

Tags: pronunciation, accent

In my legal studies class, this word cropped up and the whole class, including the teacher, couldn't pronounce it. They usually tried it several times and then ended up with different results.

Where does the accent on this word go?

> **In**-validity ?
>   In-**va**-lidity ?
>   or
>   Inva-**li**-dity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in-vuh-**lid**-i-tee

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/invalidity